# How to get List of saved games in Google Cloud save in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-games, google-cloud-save

I am integrating google play game services into my unity game. In there I am using "**google cloud save**" feature to save game status to cloud. Each and every time I save the game I am creating a filename like this "**"testfile"+(DateTime.now).toString()**" and In order to save game first we need to open the game state  with this method.

**savedGameClient.OpenWithAutomaticConflictResolution(fileName, DataSource.ReadCacheOrNetwork, ConflictResolutionStrategy.UseLongestPlaytime,
OnSavedGameOpened);**.

so like this i did 2 saves. Now the user uninstalled the game and reinstalled it. Now i want to continue from last saved check Point.

My doubt is Inorder to open the game ,we need the file name to open it . As the game was uninstalled the local saved files will be Deleted.

Is there any way to get list of saved games from developer side without ui??

I want to get the list of saved games and want to load the latest one. I already tried with the UI But i want to do it from developer side.

I am struck here . Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Once a user is authenticated and is logged in, all you need to do is call a Load. The Load will pull the newest snapshot from the cloud. What you can do then is convert the byte[] that is returned to whatever data you are saving. Then your entire save is loaded with relevant data. Use it however you like.

Comment: What I would recommend is having your fileName be a static string. Do not change it. The meta data Google stores already contains the most play time, when a save was committed, etc. as long as you set this data when saving.

Comment: If you want to keep the naming convention you have, you can use [this method from the Google Play Plugin](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity#displaying-saved-games-ui). It should load a set number of saves. From what I can tell though you just want the newest save so just use a static naming convention for save data.

Comment: @TEEBQNE so is it ok to keep the file name same for each and every save?? I thought  we have to change the file name for  every save. Beacuse we are pulling the saving game with file name so it may get conflicts?

Comment: Well, that's how you resolve the saves. There are the two methods `OpenWithAutomaticConflictResolution` and `OpenWithManualConflictResolution`. When you open a file to either save or load, you can decide how you want to handle a conflict. Google understands when it is the same user that there is no conflict, so it overwrites. The automatic conflict resolution will automatically handle conflicts for you based on preset conditions such as most time played, newest save, etc.